# How do I identify which volume contains Windows using DISKPART?

Tags: partitioning, dell, intel, rst

I'm following this process to try and install Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 13 - https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/?_ga=2.230445403.657964385.1681989042-488390009.1676802683.

At the stage to list the volumes and check which one contains Windows:

```
diskpart

list volume
```

[photo of cmd running diskpart on dell machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGUfg.jpg)

I can't tell which of these relates to Windows, I had assumed that it would be in `Label` but it doesn't seem to be. Which volume number is the right one for the next stage?

```
select volume [number]

assign letter=[letter]
```

Comment: You should ask Windows users. We users know nothing about how Windows does this. I do would like to suggest to use our gparted. a live sessions comes in handy every sp often as it does not depend on the installed OS. See https://gparted.org/livecd.php That one will show  clear labels and is native to Ubuntu so we could help with that.

Comment: That's tough - At first glance through those Ubuntu instructions, I feel that there's a better way to handle this.  The instructions should be able to provide a "pre" step where the user makes a note of the Windows partition so that they can accurately identify it later at that step.